# How can I change "Today's Tasks" on the Home page to show all tasks?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-home-page

I can go to the dropdown at the right of the Today's Tasks component and select "My Tasks," but I'd like it to come up automatically.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Very old question I know but FYI, I just tried to do this (1/21/2020) from the Lighting App Builder for the home page and it still doesn't allow you to select "My Tasks" as a default. So I'd say for now, the answer is sadly No.

Comment: Linking to existing open idea in the system :- https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXHFUA3/lightning-todays-tasks-component-more-list-views-better-defaulting